# Auto redirect users to the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, http-redirect

I want to redirect users to the previous page whenever they visit a specific page

Let's say: *page123.php*

I have the following code on that page that redirect users to the previous page but on click:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.goback').click(function() {
        history.go(-1);
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to automate the process so whenever they visit that page (*page123.php*) they redirected back to the previous one. I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me in achieving this. Thank you.

> Note: I don't want to use htaccess redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this tag to your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=yoururlhere" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm afraid I can't because I'm editing in a smarty template.

Comment: this is redirect to specific page. he asked about previous page where you don't know what the reference to call for that previous page.